# Symfony2 and guzzle compatibility

Tags: symfony, composer-php, guzzle, vendor

I have this in my composer.json:

```
"require" : {
    "php" : ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony" : "~2.3",
    "doctrine/orm" : "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "v1.2.0",
    "twig/extensions" : "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "sensio/generator-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
    "symfony/console" : "2.3.*@dev",
    "symfony/console": "v2.3.11",
    "symfony/console" : "2.3.*@dev",
    "symfony/console": "v2.3.11",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "3.9.2",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.0.3",
    "PHPOffice/PHPExcel": "1.8.*"
},
```

When I try to install the vendors, it tells me

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.3.x-dev].
- symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev requires guzzle/guzzle 3.9.2 -> no matching package found.
```

Any Idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working composer setup for Guzzle using Symfony 2.5.6:

```
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.6",

    ...

    "guzzle/batch": "~3.7",
    "guzzle/service": "~3.7",
    "guzzle/plugin": "~3.7",
    "guzzle/log": "~3.7",
```